# Enter the no.s from two columns and the numbers in between to a 3rd column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Currently, I am having a table structure as below:
[image]

I tried selecting two columns with the series and dragging it down for autofill but didn't seem to work. I need something like below. Is there any way to do this with Excel, Google Sheets or something?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a recent version of Excel, in **E2** enter the **array formula**:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ROW(INDIRECT(C2 & ":" & D2)))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
Otherwise enter the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function CSList(n1 As Long, n2 As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = n1 To n2
        CSList = CSList & "," & i
    Next i
    CSList = Mid(CSList, 2)
End Function
```

Then in **E2** enter:

```
=CSList(C2,D2)
```

and copy down:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as ***.xlsm*** rather than ***.xlsx***

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=CSList(A1,B1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

Though above solution has worked for me using Ms Excel, I was later able to solve this in Google Sheets. I am adding this answer here for those who may not have access to Ms Excel.

**Steps:**

1. Go to 'Tools' menu and click on 'Script editor...'
2. In the code file open paste the code given below and save.

   ```
   function range2series(input) {

     try {

        var r = input.split("-");
        var exist = r[1];

        //get the start and stop value
        var start = r[0];
        var last  = r[1];
        var current = start;
        var output = "";

        while (current <= last) {
          output += current;     
          output += ",";
          current++;                     
        }  

        //remove the last comma.
         output = output.substring(0, output.length - 1);
         return output;

       } catch(err) {
          //if single value and not range send back the input.
          return input; 
       }  



   }
   ```

Now you can use the function with Google sheets. Just click on a column and type `=range2series(CELL)`, for example `range2series(D4)`.

For more details, [refer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).